# Log4j 2 not logging to file

Tags: log4j2

I am trying to use log4j 2 for the first time but having trouble getting my code to log to a file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

My code is not logging to my File Appender or Console Appender:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </PatternLayout>        
    </Console>
    <File name="File" fileName="resources/app-log.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern pattern="%d{MM.dd.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </PatternLayout>
    </File>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="x.y" level="ALL" additivity="true">
      <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Logger>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Here is my Java code doping the logging:

```
    package x.y;    

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;    

    public class Foo {
            private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Foo.class.getName());

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                Foo foo = new Foo;
                logger.info("Application starting");

             }

        }
```

Edit:  My app is logging to the console but not using the pattern layout I specified.  My app is a Maven app and I have put log4j2.xml in src/main/resources.  I know my configuration xml is being read because when I put in something invalid I get an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.  Changed to:

```
<PatternLayout pattern="%d{MM.dd.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
```

Now it logging to my file.